# Error when using File.Delete release file

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    File.Delete(excelFile);
```

I am getting the following error:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\ODF1.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.

I am not sure how to release the file so it can be deleted.
I tried the following but did not work:

```
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    File.Delete(excelFile);
```

Comment: You're getting the error you mention on the File.Delete line, correct?

Comment: Whatever's *accessing it* would have to release it.  Adding code *after the exception* isn't going to stop the exception.

Comment: The Excel file is still open in another program, probably Excel. Close all instances of Excel and test the code again.

Comment: Is it your own process which is using the file, or a different one?

Comment: Are you writing to the file at all? You've probably got the file open somewhere else in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file handle has to be released by the other process. You can use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see which process is holding on to that file. Garbage collection doesn't track file handles, so the `GC` class won't help you here.